# Sanitizing Strings before inserting to DB

Tags: mysql, objective-c, sqlite, escaping

I'm getting the following error when trying to insert data into my sqlite database:

```
"sqlite near "t": syntax error"
```

and I have no idea what it means :-(

Background: I'm using `mysql_real_escape_string` to "sanitize" data coming in from an online form (the form prompts the user to enter their info into text-fields and press "submit") - and this works perfectly well: it allows all the single and double quoted characters to be accepted and entered into the DB without errors.

Next, my iPhone App queries this DB and parses the incoming data - and the interesting thing is that I then get \" and \' all over the place (as-in: don\'t  or   \"The Odyssey\" instead of don't or "The Odyssey")

To fix this I use `[stringVar stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:@""]` - so I'm basically replacing all slashes with no-space - and this works perfectly (I get: don't + "The Odyssey".)

HOWEVER, when I now try to go and WRITE this newly downloaded and parsed data to my *on-device* sqlite database - the App crashes.   And I'm fairly certain this has to do with all them single & double quotes, slashes, and who knows what else.

To test things, I created some quick dummy data that does NOT contain any of these tricky characters, inserted it to the database (during runtime) and everything worked just fine - the app didn't crash, and the on-device sqlite database displayed everything fine - so I'm fairly certain there's nothing wrong with my sqlite database, my sql statements, etc.  It must be the downloaded data/strings that are still corrupted somehow.

It goes without saying I'm no SQL expert - I basically know the bare-minimum to get by and try to learn things as I go. I've researched this and thought I found the solution with `mysql_real_escape_string` but it seems to only work one way - except I need the round-trip solution.

any tips or suggestions?

======================================

EDIT # 1 - here is the code I'm using - a hybrid what was suggested and what I'm finding in this iPhone book:

```
NSString *sqlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT OR REPLACE INTO '%@' ('%@', '%@', '%@', '%@') VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", tableName, @"Title", @"Source", @"Date", @"StoryCopy"];

NSLog(@"The sql string is = '%@'", sqlString);
const char *sql = [sqlString UTF8String];
sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
int rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &stmt, nil);
if (rc == SQLITE_OK) {
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 0, [sTitle UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, [sSource UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, [sDate UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 3, [sCopy UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
}

if (sqlite3_step(stmt) != SQLITE_DONE) {
    NSAssert(0, @"Error updating table!!!");
}

sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
```

The problem is that its inserting values into columns it shouldn't be inserting into. Its kinda all over the place. Any ideas what's wrong here?

Comment: The column indexes passed to the `sqlite3_bind_xxx` functions begin with 1, not 0. Sadly, the column indexes for the `sqlite3_column_xxx` functions are 0 based. It's confusing and error prone. Also, why are you using a string format for the table and column names? Just put the names right in the query string. And the names don't need to be quoted.

Comment: I see - good to know - I fixed it and its working well now (thanks!) Re using string format for table and column names - my initial intention was to make this method flexible enough so I could call it on ANY of the tables in my DB (hence "tableName") - which all have varying # of columns in 'em. But the code has gone through QUITE a few edits since :-) (Like just now with your fixes.) So its a bit of a mashed-up mess with all sort of junk. Frankly, right now I'm just happy to get it working on this one lonesome table - and if I have to write individual methods for each table - so be it :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are performing your queries incorrectly. There is no need to "sanitize" anything first. Make sure you don't use string formats to build your query. Instead, make proper use of `sqlite3_bind_xxx` functions.

Example:

```
sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
int rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(dbHandle, "INSERT INTO table_name (field1, field2) VALUES (?, ?)", -1, &stmt, nil);
if (rc == SQLITE_OK) {
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, [someValue UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, [otherValue UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
}
```

where `someValue` and `otherValue` are `NSString` objects. The text can contain any Unicode text. The use of `sqlite_bind_text` takes care of escaping any characters that need to be escaped.

Later, when you read the values from a query using `sqlite3_column_text`, you will get back the original text.

Comment: ... and the same applies to the PHP side: Use prepared statements instead of the terrible hack `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Comment: ok, working on it - but, when you wrote `sqlite3_statement *stmt;` did you mean `sqlite3_stmt *stmt;`?

Comment: well it doesn't crash anymore - but its also not quite working. First, I think there's another error in your code - in the 2nd `sqlite3_bind_text`, shouldn't we be incrementing 1 to 2? And so forth? Aren't those the column numbers?

Comment: Copy and paste typo. Fixed. The code I posted is meant to be a general sample to point you in the right direction. If you are still having issues, update your question with more specific details, including code.